# Installing Wxpython on centos 7

Tags: python, centos, wxpython

I am trying to install `wx-python` using the command

```
sudo yum install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n 
libwxgtk2.8-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

But, I am getting the following error

> No package python-wxgtk2.8 available.
>
> No package python-wxtools available.
>
> No package wx2.8-i18n available.
>
> No package libwxgtk2.8-dev available.
>
> No package libgtk2.0-dev available.

I am using `CentOs 7` with `Python 2.7`

Comment: You may be interested in [this question on Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/918304/how-to-install-wxpython-on-centos-6-5-python-2-7).

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython

A list of RPMs can be found at: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=wxPython